# How do I compare input with value in a file in C?

Tags: c

I am trying to compare my input with values in a certain column in a text file in c, however the result doesn't come out as expected. Either the repeated value I entered is accepted, or the value I entered is stored into the file even though the value is repeated.

```
bool isTutorIDRepeated(const char* TutorID) 
{//TutorID used as const char since the value is not defined in this boolean function
    FILE* session_fp;
    session_fp = fopen("Session_List.txt", "r");
    if (session_fp == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to open Session_List file.\n");
        return false;
    }

    char fileline[500]; //array to read each line in the file
    while (fgets(fileline, sizeof(fileline), session_fp) != NULL)
    {
        session existedsession; //struct session is declared as existedsession
        tutor existedtutor; //sturct tutor is declared too
         sscanf(fileline, "%*s %*s %*s %*s %*s %s", existedtutor.id);
        if (strcmp(existedtutor.id, TutorID) == 0)
        {
            //use string compared function to check whether the tutorid is repeating with the tutorid existed in the file or not
            return true;//TutorID already exist
            break; 
        }
    }
    fclose(session_fp);
    return false; //TutorID is unique
}
```

This is the function to determine whether the string value I entered is the same as value in the file or not.

```
void add_session()
{
    admin add_s;
    session ss;
    tutor tt;

    FILE *session_fp; 
    //declare file pointer as admin_fp
    session_fp = fopen("Session_List.txt", "a");//open Tutor_List file in append mode

    if (session_fp != NULL)
    {
        printf("Enter number of sessions you want to add: ");
        scanf("%d", &add_s.num);
        getchar();

        for(add_s.i=0; add_s.i<add_s.num; add_s.i++)
        {
            printf("\nEnter the session code: ");
            scanf("%99[^\n]%*c", ss.code);

            printf("Enter the session title: ");
            scanf("%99[^\n]%*c", ss.title);

            printf("Enter the day: ");
            scanf("%99[^\n]%*c", ss.day);

            printf("Enter the starting time: ");
            scanf("%99[^\n]%*c", ss.start_time);

            printf("Enter the location: ");
            scanf("%99[^\n]%*c", ss.location);

            printf("Enter the tutor code: ");
            scanf("%99[^\n]%*c", tt.id);

            if(isTutorIDRepeated(tt.id))
            {
                printf("The tutorID you enter is already exist, one session could only be assigned to one tutor, please enter again.");
                add_s.i--; //the count value is decrease to repeat the iteration
                continue; //jump to the next iteration
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(session_fp,"%-15s%-25s%-15s%-15s%-10s%-10s\n", ss.code, ss.title, ss.day, ss.start_time, ss.location, tt.id);
            }

            
        }
        fclose(session_fp);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Failed to open Session_List file.");
    }
}
```

The data format of the file looks like this:
[table of session list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6wyO.png)

Comment: 1. In the isTutorIDRepeated function, you are not properly reading the tutor ID from the file. The sscanf line should be modified to:
```
sscanf(fileline, "%*s %*s %*s %*s %*s %s", existedtutor.id);
```
 2. In the add_session function, you are not initializing the session and tutor structs before using them. Make sure to initialize them before reading input values. For example:
```
session ss;
tutor tt;
memset(&ss, 0, sizeof(session));
memset(&tt, 0, sizeof(tutor));
```

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre], which includes an exact copy of input that reproduces the problem (both user input and data in files, provided as text, not an image), an exact copy of the observed output, and a sample of the output desired instead. Those should be with a program that is complete (including a `main` routine and the necessary `#include` directives) but minimal (has been reduced to just enough code to reproduce the problem).